# Extract tar.gz file from Blob Storage and upload the extracted result to another Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, .net-8.0

I have this code that gets a blob storage file and extracts it, it works when I test saving the result on my computer.

Now instead of saving the file on the local computer, I want to upload the extracted result to another blob storage. My challenge relies on how can I extract the results as bytes or stream so I can upload, I did try this, and I did not get errors, but the blob is 0 bytes. Any advice is appreciated.

```
var blobEndPointSrc = "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/data-source-raw?etc...";
var blobContainerClientSrc = GetBlobServiceClientSAS(blobEndPointSrc);
var blobClientSrc = blobContainerClientSrc.GetBlobClient("file.tar.gz");
var blobDownloadInfo = blobClientSrc.OpenRead();
using Stream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(blobDownloadInfo);

// test on local drive and works.
using var tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gzipStream);
tarArchive.ExtractContents(@"D:\file");
```

Now trying to take the results and upload them to blob storage:

```
// using var tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gzipStream);
// tarArchive.ExtractContents(@"D:\file");

var tarBuffer = TarBuffer.CreateInputTarBuffer(gzipStream);
Stream result = new MemoryStream();
TarBuffer.CreateOutputTarBuffer(result);

var blobEndPointDst = = "https://storageaccountname2.blob.core.windows.net/data-source-raw?etc...";
var blobContainerClientDst = GetBlobServiceClientSAS(blobEndPointDst);
var blobClientDst = blobContainerClient1.GetBlobClient("extracted_file");
blobClientDst.Upload(result, true);
```

All blob code works fine for both upload and download. But the conversion of extract results ended up giving 0 bytes in the uploaded file.

It is also ok if another extracting library is suggested or another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I tried the following code to extract the tar.gz file from Blob Storage and upload the extracted result to another Blob Storage.*

**Code :**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace ExtractAndUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourceBlobConnectionString = "<sourceblobconne_string>";
            string destinationBlobConnectionString = "<destinationblobconne_string>";

            string sourceContainerName = "<sourceContainer_name>";
            string sourceBlobName = "<blobname.tar.gz>";
            string destinationContainerName = "<destinationContainer_name>";
            string destinationBlobName = "<destinationBlob_name>";

            var sourceBlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(sourceBlobConnectionString);
            var sourceBlobContainerClient = sourceBlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName);
            var sourceBlobClient = sourceBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(sourceBlobName);

            var downloadResponse = sourceBlobClient.Download();
            using (Stream sourceStream = downloadResponse.Value.Content)
            {
                using (var gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(sourceStream))
                {
                    using (var tarInputStream = new TarInputStream(gzipStream))
                    {
                        TarEntry entry;
                        while ((entry = tarInputStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                        {
                            if (entry.IsDirectory)
                                continue;
                            using (var result = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                tarInputStream.CopyEntryContents(result);
                                result.Position = 0;
                                var destinationBlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(destinationBlobConnectionString);
                                var destinationBlobContainerClient = destinationBlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(destinationContainerName);
                                var destinationBlobClient = destinationBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(destinationBlobName);
                                destinationBlobClient.Upload(result, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Extraction and upload completed successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully, as shown below:

```
Extraction and upload completed successfully.
```

[image]

**Sourceblob :**

[image]

**Destinationblob :**

The extracted file data was successfully saved to the destination blob, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm it works, thanks. I would added one comment. when extract, it contains multiple files, so that destinationBlobName is changed to entry.Name.